# Searching for values in array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, indexing

i'm new to coding and have been introduced to C language. I need help understanding a specific concept.

I want to know how I can search for a specific number(e.g. 4) in a array(e.g. 
{1 2 4 5 6 4 6}). How ever I want to print out the index of the last occurrence of 4. How can I do this?

I have managed to so far do this...What i don't understand is how to show the ''last occurrence of a given number''

```
#include <stdio.h>
LastIndexOf(int search, int values[], int numValues){
    int i;
    int display;
    for(i=0;i<numValues;i++){
        if(values[i] == search){
            display = i
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `display` should have this value at the end of the iteration. All you need to do is return it.

Comment: your code should work

Comment: You should indent your code properly.

Comment: If you want the index of the last occurrence, you should search from the back of the array so you can stop once you find a matching entry rather than searching the entire array every time.

Comment: Thanks guys! Very helpful comments! :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work

```
#include <stdio.h>
int LastIndexOf(int search, int values[], int numValues){
    int i;
    int display=-1;
    for(i=0;i<numValues;i++){
        if(values[i] == search){
            display = i;
        }
    }
    return display;
}

void main() {
    int display = LastIndexOf( ... );
    printf("Last occurrence at postion %i \n",display);
    return 0;
}
```

As suggested in the comments, the version going backwards is far better:

```
int LastIndexOf(int search, int values[], int numValues){
   for(int i=numValues-1;i>=0;i--){
       if(values[i] == search) {
            return  i;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you please explain why you did "int display = -1"...??

Comment: `-1` is a placeholder value for "invalid". The resulting index will be 0 or above that. So it can't be `-1`, so if in the end it still is `-1`, we know that something went wrong. For instance, the number we were searching for was not there at all.

Comment: Few remarks: `main()` should return `int`, not `void`. `display` inside `int main()` should be defined.